# Add bug screen, design / layout suggestion

Tags: usability, web-app, design

I am working on a bug tracking system, below are two design/layout I have for the 'add new bug' feature.

**Screen 1**

[image]

**Screen 2**

[image]

Which of these two screen look more intuitive ?

Any help or suggestion are also welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: To what level of user will this be exposed? 
1. a newly added bug cannot be anything but open, right? 
2. I'm not convinced severity/priority is something an end user should be able to suggest?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I totally agree with your first point, while adding the bug, the status select box make no sense. I love this site !!!

Comment: Related question (same project): [Bug tracking add new bug screen correct positioning of fields](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/44982/17023)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From speed of the interaction perspective the first design could work better.
[image]

Comment: I forgot to add a field named "Projects" where in the user select the project to which the bug needs to be added. Where and how should I position this field ?

Comment: @Yasser It depends on the typical task flow. But assuming Project is a higher element in a hierarchy I think project selection should be somewhere before adding bug and could be displayed in the breadcrumbs, i.e. `Home>Project name>Bugs>Add bug`.