# Bug tracking add new bug screen correct positioning of fields

Tags: usability, web-app, design

Below is my add new bug screen, I have the following fields, with the below layout.

I want to add an another field called "project:" which will be a a drop down filled with all project name assigned to that user. I am little out of thought on where and how to position this field.

Need some inputs/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I’d add the select list in the heading, so that it reads

```
Add bug for [project]
```

It’s the first thing a user will read, and it’s usually the first/simplest thing a user has in mind when filing a new bug. Also it will prevent cases where a user fills in a title and description and only then notices that the project she had in mind is (for whatever reason) not available.

Another suggestion: As you also seem to have the category "Enhancement", maybe you should rename "Bug" to "Issue", as an ehancement suggestion is typically not considered a bug.

```
Add issue for [project]
```

Or make the category select list part of the title, too:

```
Add [category] for [project]
```

So users can start filing new issues by selecting the category (Bug, Enhancement, …) and the project, which creates headings like "Add **enhancement** for **Cute Cats**", "Add **bug** for **Dogs need love, too**"

Answer (score 0):

A good website to refer to for filing bugs you might want to take a look at  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

In this case,
I will put the project dropdown list field just before the submit button.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, i checked bugzilla and found the project field to be just below the title, can u pls share some screenshot

Comment: Hi Yasser, both below the title or above the submit button would be a good approach. I don't think I will need to share some screenshot, it's pretty straightforward. Simon